# vba: adding workbook to collection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add an object workbook in the collection created. However, when I add a watch to the collection, I see the item1, but it says there is no variable, but there should be a workbook specified by the path.

Do you have any idea where my mistake could come from?

```
Sub AddWbkToCollection()

    Dim Path As String        
    Dim Coll As Collection        
    Dim wbk As Workbook        
    Set Coll = New Collection

    Path = WshCockpit.Range("Path")        

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path)

    Coll.Add wbk, wbk.Name

    wbk.Close

    Set wbk = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal? I mean you close the `wbk` right after you put it into the collection `wbk.Close`. So how can it stay in the collection then? It is only in the collection as long as it is opened. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My goal at first was to add a dozens of workbooks into the collection in order to be able to refer to them furthermore in.the code without opening them everytime but save them into the collection. Isn't it possible ?

Comment: No it's not possible. You need to open a file to access it.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path)
> ```

`wbk` isn't an object. it's a *reference* to an object, and that object is owned by Excel.

```
wbk.Close
```

Beyond this point, the `wbk` refers to an object that's gone. So there's still a reference in your collection, but it's a reference to *nothing*. VBA knows it's an object; `IsObject` returns `True`, `wbk Is Nothing` returns `False`.

But then, this throws an *automation error*:

```
Debug.Print wbk.Name
```

Because the object itself is gone. A `Workbook` object doesn't exist if it's not opened in Excel.

Therefore, a user collection of workbooks is redundant: `Application.Workbooks` contains all the workbooks you're ever going to need.